# How do I disable/change the NFC sounds?

Tags: notifications, nfc

I love the NFC functionality of my LG L5, but the sounds are too annoying.

**Is there a way to customize or disable the sounds that are played whenever a tag was read?**

Answer (score 1):

Most Android sounds are in .apk files and are a pain to edit. You have to find a way to open them, then you can remove or edit the sound, finally you have to package them up and sign them.

It's much easier to use [NFC Task Launcher](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.jwsoft.nfcactionlauncher).

Answer (score 0):

I finally figured out how to do this, at least on my phone (OnePlus One).

You have to first install the [Xposed framework](http://repo.xposed.info/module/de.robv.android.xposed.installer), then install [this](http://repo.xposed.info/module/pk.qwerty12.nfclockscreenoffenabler) module.  In the module configuration, there are several settings, including the ability to disable some or all of the NFC-related sounds.

Usual caveats about backing up first apply, since the Xposed framework does some pretty low-level hacking, but all the modules I've experimented with have had no issues.